# How can i display more than one row in my table USING PHP & MYSQL database

Tags: php, html

I'm having issues to display all the rows inside my database table. But only one rows display instead of all data.

```
$query= mysqli_query($conn,"select* from food_table");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

        echo "<p style='color: green;'>See Below the Available Foods<br></p>";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $food_name= $row['food_name'];
            $food_info = $row['food_info'];
            $food_price = $row['food_price'];
            $vendor_id = $row['vendor_id'];
            $default_miles = $row['default_miles'];
            $food_date= $row['date'];
            
        }



$foods= array($food_name,$food_info,$food_price,$vendor_id,$default_miles, $food_date );

    foreach($foods as $foodss){

        echo "$foodss.<br/>";
    }
```

please see result below;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc4iQ.png)

Comment: Put the part that runs `echo` on the row _inside_ the while loop.

Comment: Thanks... But i still don't get it...

Comment: I think I'm getting it now... Let me try more.. I will tell you if i get it.. Thanks.. I appreciate you all.. Much love

Answer (score 0):

You've got your loops wrong. You first loop through all rows in the database and assign them to the variables `$food_name` etc, however, only after you exit the while loop you create an array with those variables. This doesn't work, as now the `$food_name` etc just has the value of the last row.

What you'd want is something like this:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

     $food_name= $row['food_name'];
     $food_info = $row['food_info'];
     $food_price = $row['food_price'];
     $vendor_id = $row['vendor_id'];
     $default_miles = $row['default_miles'];
     $food_date= $row['date'];

      echo $food_name . "<br/>;
            
}
```

Now you put the food name for every row on the page.

Always keep in mind what your loop is actually doing. Every iteration of the while loop you set the variables `$food_name` to a certain value. Print the value in the current iteration to get all values on the page. If you want to store those values in an array, you would have to do something like `$food_names[] = $row['food_name']`.

Comment: Thanks... I need more explanation on this... Please

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all data inside a array before display or you can print it inside while loop. best practice is store data inside array first.

```
$query= mysqli_query($conn,"select* from food_table");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

        echo "<p style='color: green;'>See Below the Available Foods<br></p>";
        $foods = array() //initialize an empty array
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $food_name= $row['food_name'];
            $food_info = $row['food_info'];
            $food_price = $row['food_price'];
            $vendor_id = $row['vendor_id'];
            $default_miles = $row['default_miles'];
            $food_date= $row['date'];

            array_push($foods,$food_name,$food_info,$food_price,$vendor_id,$default_miles,$food_date);
            
        }


    foreach($foods as $foodss){

        echo "$foodss.<br/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: ($foods array goes within while loop to store all data)

```
$foods = [];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $food_name= $row['food_name'];
    $food_info = $row['food_info'];
    $food_price = $row['food_price'];
    $vendor_id = $row['vendor_id'];
    $default_miles = $row['default_miles'];
    $food_date= $row['date'];
    $foods[] =[$food_name,$food_info,$food_price,$vendor_id,$default_miles, $food_date];
}
```

//foreach code as it is

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).